# binding to a radio button

Tags: wpf, radio-button, bind

I have the following radio button bound to the variable `IsAllowed`

```
<RadioButton Name="YesRadioButton" Margin="5,5,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsAllowed, Mode=TwoWay}">Yes</RadioButton>
```

How can I make the No button to take the opposite value only using XAML ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Xaml-only solution.  You could bind No using a reverse bool Converter though.

```
<local:NotConverter x:Key="notConverter"/>

{Binding IsAllowed, Mode=TwoWay, Converter=notConverter} 

public class NotConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Boolean result = false;
        if (value is Boolean)
            result = !((Boolean)value);
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Boolean result = false;
        if (value is Boolean)
            result = !((Boolean)value);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: and how i bind it to the No button ?

Comment: {Binding IsAllowed, Mode=TwoWay, Converter=notConverter}

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to. It will happen by default.

Just make sure that `IsAllowed` starts off as `true`, and the rest will take care of its self.

This is because when you click on the `No` button, it will automatically set the `Yes` button's checked value (that's how radio buttons work), so the change will happen automatically and you backing class will be updated.

EVEN BETTER: Just use a check box. Yes/no situations are what they are designed for.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write converter using [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).  Here is an example how to do it [WPF - Bind to Opposite Boolean Value Using a Converter](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/OppositeBoolConverter.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The above answer works but I wanted a converter that would apply to both Yes and No radio buttons and reflect the value of nullable booleans. So I made the alternative that takes advantage of converter parameters:

```
public class YesNoRadioButtonToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return CompareValueWithRequiredValueToBeChecked(value, parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return CompareValueWithRequiredValueToBeChecked(value, parameter);
    }

    private bool CompareValueWithRequiredValueToBeChecked(object value, object parameterValue)
    {
        bool? convertedValue = ConvertObjectToBool(value);
        bool? convertedParameter = ConvertObjectToBool(parameterValue);

        bool result = convertedValue == convertedParameter;

        return result;
    }

    private bool? ConvertObjectToBool(object parameter)
    {
        string stringResult = parameter == null ? null : parameter.ToString();
        bool? convertedResult;

        bool convertResultTest = false;
        if (stringResult != null && !bool.TryParse(stringResult, out convertResultTest))
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException(string.Format("Cannot convert {0} to a bool.", parameter));
        }

        convertedResult = stringResult == null ? (bool?)null : (bool?)convertResultTest;

        return convertedResult;
    }
}
```

Here is what the XAML looks like:

```
    <converters:YesNoRadioButtonToBooleanConverter x:Key="yesNoToBool" />

    <RadioButton Content="Yes" Name="radYes" GroupName="Group1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=boolProperty1, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource yesNoToBool}, ConverterParameter=true}" />
    <RadioButton Content="No" Name="radNo" GroupName="Group1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=boolProperty1, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource yesNoToBool}, ConverterParameter=false}" />
```